# Python Flask Login login_required redirecting

Tags: python, flask, flask-login

I am working on a Flask app and using Flask-Login for authentication. Everything is set up and running. However when the user logins in and attempts to visit a page that requires login, they are redirected to the login page.

When watching the console, I get a 200 for the GET login page, a 200 for the POST on the login, a 302 from the login page to the home page, and then another 302 from the homepage back to login.

See code below.

```
from flask import (Flask, render_template, g, flash, redirect, url_for,
                    request)
from flask_bcrypt import check_password_hash
from flask_login import (LoginManager, UserMixin, login_required, login_user,
                        logout_user, current_user)

import models
import forms

application = Flask(__name__)
application.secret_key = "xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx"
login_manager = LoginManager()
login_manager.init_app(application)
login_manager.login_view = "login"

@application.before_request
def before_request():
    g.db = models.DATABASE
    g.db.connect()
    g.user = current_user

@application.after_request
def after_request(response):
    g.db.close()
    return response

@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(email):
    try:
        return models.User.select().where(
                                models.User.email == email).get()
    except models.DoesNotExist:
        return None

@application.route("/register", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def register():
    form = forms.RegisterForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        flash("Yay! You registered!", "success")
        models.User.create_user(
            email = form.email.data,
            password = form.password.data
        )
        return redirect(url_for('home'))
    return render_template('register.html',form=form)

@application.route("/login", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    form = forms.LoginForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        next = request.args.get('next')
        try:
            user = models.User.get(models.User.email == form.email.data)
        except models.DoesNotExist:
            flash("Your email or password doesn't match!", "error")
        else:
            if check_password_hash(user.password, form.password.data):
                login_user(user, remember=True)
                flash("Welcome back!", "success")
                return redirect(next or url_for("home"))
            else:
                flash("Your email or password doesn't match!", "error")
    return render_template("login.html", form=form)

@application.route("/logout")
@login_required
def logout():
    logout_user()
    flash("You've been logged out!", "success")
    return redirect(url_for("home"))

@application.route("/")
@login_required
def home():
    return render_template("home.html")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    models.initialize()
    application.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

Here is the model:

```
import datetime

from flask_login import UserMixin
from flask_bcrypt import generate_password_hash, check_password_hash
from peewee import *

DATABASE = MySQLDatabase("fakedatabasename", host="fakehostname", user="fakeusername", password="fakepassword")


class BaseModel(Model):
    class Meta:
        database = DATABASE


class Preachers(BaseModel):
    preacher_id = PrimaryKeyField()
    preacher_first_name = CharField(max_length=27)
    preacher_last_name = CharField(max_length=27)
    preacher_email = CharField()


class Sermons(BaseModel):
    sermon_id = PrimaryKeyField()
    sermon_title = CharField(max_length=27)
    sermon_description = CharField(max_length=140)
    sermon_date = DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now())
    sermon_preacher_id = IntegerField()
    sermon_video_uri = CharField(max_length=255)


class User(UserMixin,BaseModel):
    user_id = PrimaryKeyField()
    email = CharField(index=True, unique=True)
    password = CharField()
    date_created = DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now())

    @classmethod
    def create_user(cls, email, password):
        try:
            cls.create(
                email = email,
                password = generate_password_hash(password)
            )
        except IntegrityError:
            raise ValueError("User already exists")


def initialize():
    DATABASE.connect()
    DATABASE.create_tables([Preachers, Sermons, User], safe=True)
    DATABASE.close()
```

Comment: although you are running local, please dont share secret keys

Comment: You should change the secret key now. That’s a huge security vulnerability.

Comment: What does your `User` model look like? Are you returning `self.email` from `User.get_id`?

Comment: Are you handling and displaying flashed error messages in `login.html`?  If so, which error (if any) are you seeing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out that when working with Peewee and Flask-Login, you need to let Peewee supply its default primary key for the User model instead of using a custom one. Removing `user_id = PrimaryKeyField()`, dropping the table, and restarting fixed it.